# SQL diff between rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with following structure

```
ID                  newSatus                    modifiedDate
252123_001          Closed                      2020-10-07 20:14:57.477
252123_001          Shipped                     2020-10-07 09:24:12.693
252309_001          Closed                      2020-10-08 18:51:34.810
252309_001          Shipped                     2020-10-07 09:22:33.537
252404_001          Closed                      2020-10-07 12:25:10.270 
252404_001          Shipped                     2020-10-07 09:29:02.363
```

Basically what i would like to do is have an access query that calculates the date difference for consecutive records between different newStatus but for the same ID.
The expected result would be !!

```
ID                  diffHours               diffMinutes             diffSeconds
252123_001          10h:50m:45s             650                     39045
252309_001          1 day 9h:29m:01s        2009                    120541
252404_001          2h:56m:08s              176                     10568
```

And finally calculates de median of time between these results.

Comment: SSMS isn't compatible with MySQL; why have you tagged both?

Comment: How do you know this is [tag:ms-access], @GordonLinoff? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Do I see this correctly, there are always two rows with the same ID and you want to subtract their lesser time from the greater time?

Comment: @Larnu, I suspect @GordonLinoff tagged `ms-access` due to the "... have an _access_ query..." part in the question.

Comment: Why I wondered if I had missed something obvious, @Sander . If the OP truly *is* using Access, that makes their initial choice of tagging [tag:mysql] and [tag:ssms] even *more* confusing.

Comment: @Larnu . . . MySQL is a default tag on the site.  SSMS connects to MS Access and both are Microsoft products.

Comment: *"MySQL is a default tag on the site."* Stack Overflow doesn't have "default" tags, @GordonLinoff . That would be awful as a UX if it did; for both those asking and (more so) for those answering. It's used as an example in the tags box when it's empty, but so too is pandas and ruby (and the question wasn't tagged with either of those)

Comment: correct @ThorstenKettner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to aggregate your rows so as to get one result row per ID. "Per ID" translates to `GROUP BY id` in SQL.

```
select
  id,
  datediff ("h", min(modifieddate), max(modifieddate)) as diff_hours,
  datediff ("n", min(modifieddate), max(modifieddate)) as diff_minuts,
  datediff ("s", min(modifieddate), max(modifieddate)) as diff_seconds
from mytable
group by id
order by id;
```

I must admit that I don't know how to get the median from this in MS Access, as this is the RDBMS farthest from the SQL standard that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to ungroup the data so that you have seperate column for status `Closed` and `Shipped`? The you can use simple subtraction to get the difference in time, and from that you can calculate all the things you mentioned.

Comment: This feels like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No, he already bring data like this.